# first-child not affecting the first element as expected

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why does the rule not affect the first div? (with the "update 1" text)

```css
.update div {
    width:100%;
    height:25%;
    border-top:1px dashed {color:background title};
    padding: 5px;
    color:{color:links nav};
    cursor:pointer;
}

.update div:first-child{
   border:none;
}

.update div:hover{
    color:{color:links nav hover};
}

.update div:hover > .symbol{
    color:{color:links nav};
}
```

```html
<div class="nav update">
    <a><div><div class="symbol">×</div> update 1</div></a>
    <a><div><div class="symbol">×</div> update 2</div></a>
    <a><div><div class="symbol">×</div> update 3</div></a>
    <a><div><div class="symbol">×</div> update 4</div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What does `color:{color:links nav};` mean?

Comment: What is the expected result here? The code you've provided works properly in so far as none of the divs have a border but I suspect that's not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are no divs in your code that are the first child of the `.update` div. You'd need to do something like this:

```
.update a:first-child > div {
   border:none;
}
```

Although HTML5 allows block elements like divs inside inline elements, I wouldn't do it myself. Perhaps consider spans instead.

To explain the "first child" concept a little more: in your code, each `a` element is a child of the `.update` div. The divs within those `a` elements are not children of the `.update` div; rather, they are children of the `a` elements. Each `a` element in your code only has one child div, though; and each of *those* child divs has another child div. So for an element to be a child, it must sit directly inside the parent element—one level down, as it were.

Comment: But his CSS does not require that the divs be children of `.update`, only that they be descendants.

Comment: @torazaburo I agree, but for some reason, <del>I had to be more specific with `.update`'s descendants. The CSS selector `.update div` did not target any divs at all.  In order to get any borders on the divs I used `.update a div`. Am I missing something? Is there something about a block inside an inline that changes selector behavior?</del> Disregard, there was a typo  0_o

Comment: Disregard, there was a typo  0_o

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

There are some mistakes:

The value of `color` is [a name, 6 or 3 hexadecimal number, or RGB/RGBa, or HSL/HSLa](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/color/) 
I've never seen `{color:links nav}` as a value before... is this actually working?

As @torazaburo and @Ralph.M pointed out, your divs qualify as `first-child`as well as `first-of-type` of `a` only, so your `.update` is not the direct ancestor (i.e. parent) of any div. Therefore you need more specificity by going through each level of the hierarchy.

1. `div.update.nav`
2. `a`
3. `div`

Try this:

```
  .update a:first-child div:first-of-type
```

**Note:** In your circumstance `first-child` and `first-of-type` works the same, the difference I can think that might be of concern is if you use `first-child` and `nth-child` the `n-th` variable counts differently than `nth-type-of`.

The `:first-of-type` selector in CSS allows you to target the first occurrence of an element within its container.

```css
.update div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  border-top: 2px dashed red;  /* this is a color name */
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);  /* this is RGB */
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(250,250,250,.7);  /* this is RGBa */
}
.update a:first-of-type div:first-of-type {
  border: none;
}
.update div:hover {
  color: hsl(240, 60%, 50%);  /* this is HSL */
}
.update div:hover > .symbol {
  color: hsla(324, 100%, 50%, .8);  /* this is HSLa */
}
```

```html
<div class="nav update">
  <a>
    <div>
      <div class="symbol">×</div>update 1
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div>
      <div class="symbol">×</div>update 2
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div>
      <div class="symbol">×</div>update 3
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div>
      <div class="symbol">×</div>update 4
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

See [**ARTICLE**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/)

Comment: Why does this fix the problem?

Comment: As the ARTICLE says, on the first sentence: > The `:first-of-type` selector in CSS allows you to target the first occurrence of an element within its container.

Comment: But all the divs here are **both** first-child **and** first-of-type.